# How to find pixel per meter

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a static camera through which I am focusing on the covered area, total covered area by a camera is

```
length 78.7 cm
width 102.1 cm
heigh 118.5 cm
```

my image size is `800 * 480`

now in the total covered area, I have another box whose

```
length is 22.6 cm
width is 25.6 cm
height is 24 cm
```

I want to find out how many pixels I have per meter. I am using the formula of

`m/pixels * 0.39` but it's not giving the exact answer.

Comment: You can not do this unless the camera  is calibrated. Your camera is 2D, the world 3D. A pixel in the backgroudn and foregroudn have different sizes in meters.

Comment: What if i want to count only of foreground ?

Comment: As you are aware, because I suspect you have eyes, things in the foreground are not at the same distance! there are not just 2 planes of view.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a software development question as defined in the [help].

Answer (score 2):

Many manufacturers use the pixels per meter measure as a metric of video surveillance image quality. For instance, you need around 130 ppm to have enough detail to accurately recognize facial detail and indentify license plates.

To calculate pixel density (pixel per meter) you need the number of horizontal pixels of the image or video source and the width in meters of the scene where you are looking at.

Therefore,

ppm = ImageWidth (in pixels) / Field of view (in meters)

The easiest way to calculate ppm for an specific scene is to point the camera where you want to calculate ppm, and then divide the number of pixels of your image by the distance in meters of the field of view of you camera in that specific point. Note that this measure will not be constant across the vertical axis of your camera. Each line of your image will have a different pixel density.

If you calibrate the camera you could do these calculations theoretically, since you could know the width of the field of view in advance, but it is a little bit more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Your static camera will have a specific fixed lens size determining the focal length (f number). This means that there is a specific ideal focus point along the depth of view, this 2D plane of focus will form a parabolic shape proportional to the shape and size of the lens and because lens size and FOV are inversely proportional to one another the larger your lens size, the small the FOV and as someone already mentioned the focus point diminishes outwards in all directions from the center point of your focal area (think Doppler effect) this is why we tend to find blurry pixels in the corners of images/video with object outside foreground / background of the focus plane.

This is a beautiful problem to solve using math.

so by calculating the length of the hypotenuse vs the height of a right angle triangle you know the difference in focal distance between your  focal point and the most outer pixel displayed from your image sensor and because you should know the resolution of your camera you can calculate the loss of pixel density from center in all directions.

i feel like there probably a clean looking formula to calculate this using that sly ol' dog Pi but i couldn't be bothered.

You might find this useful as step 1:
https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/right-triangle-side-angle

with the above calculator:

hypotenuse = C = distance from camera to outer most pixel capture

Height of triangle = b = distance from camera to focal point (center of your photo)

half the FOV angle = α (you would do this for both vertical and horizontal FOV per pixel example 2MP - 1920 x 1080 points of references)

every lens size has a specific vertical and horizontal FOV angle.

This will allow you to calculate which parts of objects in the scene are within perfect focus thus retaining the densest pixels.

PS if you wanted to be scientifically accurate you would need to calculate this for every pixel on your image sensor over the size of the sensor so if you had a 2MP camera you would need to do 1920 x 1080 / 1/3" (calculate the pixel density over your sensor)for example. the quality of the glass of your lens will also play a factor just not sure on what front.

The colour of the objects in the scene, atmospheric conditions and lux level in scene will allow for variable light wavelengths to the camera, also influencing the density pixels captured.

lastly because you want to calculate the resultant conversion of resolution captured vs displayed your display medium will influence the actual performance.

realistically you wouldnt be able to tell with certainty unless you measure every single distance of every pixel path from pixel on sensor to object point.

let us know how it goes. i could also be completely wrong LOL

Answer (score 1):

You can't calculate the number of pixels per meter unless you know the distance to the object being captured. An object 10 meters away will have fewer pixels per meter than an object 1 meter away. All you can accurately calculate is the number of pixels per degree of your camera's field of view.

Even if you point the camera at a flat wall, the distance from the camera to the wall will change as the incident angle changes, so distance of the middle of the wall will be closer to the camera than the distance from the corners of the wall. This can be calculated using some simple trigonometry.

Comment: Camera is 3 meter away from object

Comment: No, the camera is 3 meters away from the object is a straight line, but if you measure from the camera to a different point on the object it will be a slightly different distance. Think of it like this: stand 10 cm away from a person and look at their eyes. Now look at their feet. The eyes are much closer to your eyes than their feet even though you are 10 cms away from them.

Comment: but what if i want to count only from eye to eye

Comment: You want to count the size in meters of a single pixel and you know the exact distance from the camera to the point on the object? If this is the case you can do the calculation using trig functions, but you don't need a computer or a camera to do this.

Comment: that what i need to found which trig function

Comment: This should get you where you want to go: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-finding-side-right-triangle.html